# Is it possible to for an Ionic(5) Capacitor(3) application to complete an Open ID (Auth0) flow?

Tags: ionic-framework, openid-connect, capacitor

I am struggling to utlise the angular-auth-oidc-client to add OIDC workflows into my Ionic app (android), although I feel the issues are more Capacitor so not sure that the library is the issue.  There are numerous (old) posts on Google of people who have had similar problems, so I'm trying to ascertain the current state of play.  I can:

1. By utilising a custom android scheme in my AndroidManifest, and an 'appUrlOpen' listener in app.component my OIDC login page loads in the Chrome browser on the device, and then returns to the Ionic app and opens the correct app page. Unfortunately because I've opened the login in Chrome it hangs around in the background with the username and password populated. I've no handle to it to close it, and the Capacitor plugins don't help me here.
2. Alternatively, I can add my ID Provider domain into 'AllowNavigation' in capacitor.config.json. This opens my login page in the app's webview, begins the redirect on successful login but fails (hangs) because Capacitor is not loaded when it attempts Window.Capacitor.triggerevent calls.

This is probably classed as a poor question, and I appreciate that it is light on code, but I'm interested in whether anyone has actually managed to do this successfully, as there are so many dead ends on google and github of people who've given up!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to complete an Open ID Flow on ionic with capacitor.

You need a capacitor plugin to do so, ionic provides an own payed plugin (https://ionic.io/docs/auth-connect), other alternatives exist.

angular-auth-oidc-client out of the box works only on browser, not on iOS or Android. It seems that some adoption can be made, see https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/807.